# Avoiding $0$ in the $\log()$ function

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms

I have an issue with my costfunction:

$$\sum A_{ij}\cdot\log(p_{ij})+(1-A_{ij})\cdot \log(1-p_{ij})$$

Where $p_{ij} = sigmoid(-\|z_i-z_j\|+\beta)$ and $A_{ij}$ is $1$ if connected $0$ if not.

Im solving this numerically using stochastic gradient decent, however after sufficently many iterations the $p_{ij}$ term becomes $0$ and the $\log$ returns $-\infty$ which ruins the rest of the sum.

If it is possible, can I rewrite the cost function so that the 0 value in $p_{ij}$ does not make the $-\infty$ situation occur?

Comment: Couldn't you write a "penalty function" version of your objective function where it gets penalized whenever $p_{ij}$ or $1-p_{ij}$ get tiny?

Comment: I guess that could be a solution, I was searching for a nifty log trick, if it would be possible to rewrite the expression so the $p_{ij} = 0$ didnt make the log function evaluate to $-\inf$

Comment: Replace $\log(p_{ij})$ with $\log(\theta+p_{ij})$, where $\theta$ is the minimum of the floating point type. After you do this, most likely, you'll learn that your cost function is the real problem, and the $-\infty$ is just a symptom of that.

Comment: This was caused by numerical instability, it was eventually fixed by using a lower learning rate